# Getting a serial number from a Motorola MC9200

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sdk, barcode-scanner, serial-number

How do I grab the serial number of a MC9200 scanner?

I am using the MC92N0 SDK in Visual Studios 2008 with the Symbol libraries but can't figure out how to retrieve the serial number of the device.

I see people referencing Symbol.resourcecoordination.dll but I do not have that anywhere and can't find a developers guide that can help.